# How to search the shortest distance between points using structure?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

This is my homework:
Define a structure Point with two members (x coordinate, y coordinate). Define a structure array with N elements (each element is a Point structure variable) and initialize all elements with some given values. Define a function with two formal parameters: (1) structure array SA, (2) array length N, to identify and output the shortest distance between two points (among all the point-pairs in the array). Call this function with the above-defined array and length as the actual parameters.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

//the struct for point a and b
struct Point
{
    double x,y;
};

//fuction to return the distance between two points
double pointDist(struct Point a, struct Point b)
{
    return sqrt((a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y) + (a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x));
}

//function to return the shortest distance
double shortestDist(struct Point SA[], int N)
{
    if(N == 1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    double shortestDistance = pointDist(SA[0], SA[1]);
    for(int i = 0; i != N-1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j != N; ++j)
        {
            if(shortestDistance > pointDist(SA[i], SA[j]))
            {
                shortestDistance = pointDist(SA[i], SA[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

//driver
int main()
{
    struct Point SA[4] = {{1,2}, {1,3},{3,1},{2,1}};
    printf("The shortest distance between points are %f", shortestDist(SA, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

But the shortest distance is always 0.00, I don't know which part is wrong.

Comment: There is no `return` statement in your function (after the loops)

Comment: Generally, stuff like this is best solved by launching your favourite debugger and single-stepping through the code.

Comment: Oh and also do yourself and stop trouble-shooting bugs that the compiler already found and told you about. See [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) If you follow those instructions, your compiler would have told you `error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

Comment: Aside: `sqrt((a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y) + (a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x));` --> `hypot(a.y - b.y, a.x - b.x)`

Comment: You can speed up the execution by not taking square root until you have found the smallest square.

Comment: @WeatherVane Good point.

Answer (score 2):

**Enable all compiler warnings to save time**  [@Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69752253/how-to-search-the-shortest-distance-between-points-using-structure/69752655#comment123294800_69752253)

---

```
double shortestDist(struct Point SA[], int N) {
    ...
    // Add a final return
    return shortestDistance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved already